# Using twitter bootstrap in a theme

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I made a simple web template using basic HTML and twitter bootstrap along with my own custom CSS. I want to convert that into a WordPress theme.

I know how to create WP theme from basic template . But how can I integrate twitter bootstrap with it?

If I put `bootstrap.css`, `bootstrap-responsive.css`, `custom.css` (my custom CSS file) into the CSS folder of WordPress theme, and `bootstrap.min.js` into my js folder of wp theme , will it work?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: not yet , I want to be sure before move on

Comment: Why would it *not* work?

Comment: You learn by trying, always try and then ask, saves you so much time and you get a nice feeling of accomplishment from it too

Comment: As Yoda said: “Do or do not... there is no try.” Or, Nike: "Just do it!". Don't be scared to get your hands dirty. Yoda (again): “Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.”

Answer (score 4):

Almost.

Put the bootstrap stuff in your theme, and include it on the front end using `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` in `functions.php`

e.g. for the bootstrap js:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

And for bootstrap.css:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' );
function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
    // Respects SSL, Style.css is relative to the current file
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css';
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
```

Comment: Hey Tom, I'm just curious if you've worked with starter themes such as hybrid core, toolbox & _S ( maintained by Automattic Theme team ) and bootstrap together? What's your recommendation  as to how to tie these starter themes with bootstrap? If you like, you can answer this question of mine at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108970/how-to-integrate-the-twitter-bootstrap-into-s-in-the-most-future-proof-way?noredirect=1#comment151933_108970  thx.

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes little sense, perhaps you mean you want to integrate the two? The question you linked to is huge and unclear/vague